# Updating a label as a user is typing

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

It seems like I need to use

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
label.text = textField.text;    
}
```

and maybe something like this in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textViewDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}
```

It crashes on entering text if I do it like this...  Otherwise it just updates when its completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textViewDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

with

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textViewDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

since your method takes a parameter: the text field itself. This argument is part of the selector and represented by the colon.

**Or** just implement the UITextView delegate methods: there's a value-changed-callback, too.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need last line.  Use `textField.delegate=self;` instead.

Comment: That's because in your **- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
label.text = textField.text;    
}**
textField is not equal to textView

Comment: Change texField to textView or viceversa